# XPath одного уровня

Tags: c#, xpath

Привет имеется часть код страницы, не могу спарсить элементы одного уровня

```
<tr class="even" role="row">
  <td class="text-left" data-sort="6">TEXT</td>
  <td class="text-right" data-sort="18">
  <td> 102 </td>
  <td class="text-right" data-sort="19">11</td>
  <td> 14 </td>
  <td class="text-right" data-sort="16">
  <td data-sort="15.84">0</td>
</tr>
```

Нужно спарсит строку `<td> 102 </td>`, на прямую не получиться т.к. идет список `<tr class="even" role="row">` и искать нужно уже внутри.
Нахожу нужный заголовок по TEXT, а как спарсить уже на одном уровне не знаю

```
//td[@class='text-left' and contains(text(), 'TEXT')]
```

Что нужно дописать к моему коду?

Comment: Не хватает двух закрывающих тегов `</td>` - так и должно быть?

Answer (score 1):

Как я понял, нужно получить значения узлов `td`, которые не содержат атрибутов.

XPath-выражение может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
string xpath = "//tr[td[@class='text-left' and contains(text(), 'TEXT')]]/td[not(@*)]";
```

Ищется узел `tr`, содержащий узел `td` с нужными атрибутами и текстом. А потом берутся узлы `td` без атрибутов.

```
// Получаем один (первый) элемент td
var node = doc.SelectSingleNode(xpath);

// Получаем все элементы td
var nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Answer (score 1):

решил проблему так

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using System.Net;

string text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//td[@class='text-left' and contains(text(), 'TEXT']/parent::tr/td[n]")).Text;
```

В проекте много библиотек, но использовал для selenium webdriver

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё указать, какая библиотека используется.